# How to make the Script component of a GameObject inherit from its parent, including the Start method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is in the context of creating an RTS, in which the aim is to have several Units (Buildings; Movers : Workers, Soldiers...) that one can select as one or a group. When selected, the units can be moved (Mover), and can have specific methods (Building: can create a Mover...).

I have (heavily) based the selection system on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAVi04mzeKk

I have a class `Unit`, which is added upon Start within the `unitList` field of the class `UnitSelections` (this makes all `Unit` objects of the Scene accessible for selection):

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth;
    public int health;
    public bool isSelected = false;
    public bool canMove = false;
    public bool canCreateUnits = false;
    public bool canAttack = false;
    public bool canGatherResources = false;

    void Start()
    {
        //add this unit to the list
        UnitSelections.Instance.unitList.Add(this);
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        //remove it from the list when destroyerd
        UnitSelections.Instance.unitList.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

The class `UnitSelections` holds the data on all `Unit` objects in the Scene, and all `Unit` objects that are currently selected. It includes methods on how to select them (via left click, drag + left click, shift + left click...):

```
public class UnitSelections : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Unit> unitList = new List<Unit>();
    public List<Unit> unitsSelected = new List<Unit>();

    private static UnitSelections _instance;
    public static UnitSelections Instance { get { return _instance; }
    //more code with methods to add units to the unitsSelected
}
```

And then a class `Building`, child of `Unit`, which has a method that can be triggered if the field isSelected is TRUE (create a Mover object). This is to say, when the Building is selected, only then can you trigger its methods via e.g. keyboard input:

```
public class Building : Unit
{
    void Start()
    {
        canCreateUnits = true;
        maxHealth = 1000;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) && this.isSelected)
        {
            CreateMover();
        }
    }

    void CreateMover()
    {
        // behaviour here
    }
}
```

In the unity editor, I have a prefab which corresponds to the Building subClass:
[image: Building Class in Editor]

If I add as a component the script Building.cs to the GameObject Building, does it inherit everything from Unit.cs ?
Or does it need to have the Unit script as a component too ?

--> For fields and "normal" methods (not Start/Awake/Update), yes. So the GameObject Building only needs to have the Script Component `Building`

However, the Start method of `Unit` is not called in the `Building` class, which makes it not possible to add it to the unitList field of the class `UnitSelections`.
How can the Start method of `Unit` be called for an object with the `Building` Script Component ?

--> Need `protected virtual void Start()` for the `TopClass`, and can call `base.Start()` within the `protected override void Start()` of the `ChildClass`

See solution answer for details

Comment: Design-wise you should mark `Unit` as `abstract` since it adds nothing to your game, you really need something like `Building` since it is the type with implemented methods of note such as `Start` and `Update`.   Herein is the problem though - Unity will **only** call methods like `Start`, `Update`, `Awake` etc on types that no other types derive from. i.e. `Building`.   So if you derived a new type called `Highrise` like so `public class Highrise : Building { void Start() { ... } }`, Unity will now call `Start` in `Highrise` and ignore the one in `Building`.  This has nothing to do with `new`

Comment: ...you can get around it easily by making your base class `abstract` then anytime you need to implement a Unity method whack it in the base class and have the method call a virtual method that child classes can override.  e.g. `public abstract class Unit : MonoBehaviour { void Start () { OnStart(); }  protected virtual  void OnStart() { }`.  That or use composition.

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for explaining this, it is too in-depth for me to implement  yet, but I am sure this will come in very useful after some experience ! (also I am building an RTS so it's likely that Unit will have methods on it I think)

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `Unit` inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, `Building` inherits `Unit` (which inherits `MonoBehaviour`). As such, you should ONLY add Building as a component to your GameObject. If you add both, you'll end up with two distinct components on your game object - the Building component AND a Unit component. Each component would have it's own set of variables, and listen and react to the Unity messages independently, for example `Update()` if it were present if both classes.

It's also interesting to note that `MonoBehaviour` inherits from `Behaviour`, which inherits from `Component`, which inherits from `Object` (UnityEngine.Object, not System.Object). So `Building.cs` in this case is just another subclass of a component and is treated as such. You can check out the lineage on the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) pages.

This image demonstrates the problem, where each component has it's own set of field values.

[image: Two Components With Separate Values]

Now, if we create a small test script to look at the GameObject:
[image]

We get this as the result:
[image]

As you can see, there are two "Unit" components on the HumanBarracks GameObject, a Unit and a Building which is also of type Unit.

---

**Extra**

```csharp
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth;
    public int health;
    public bool isSelected = false;
    public bool canMove = false;
    public bool canCreateUnits = false;
    public bool canAttack = false;
    public bool canGatherResources = false;

    // By making Start protected virtual, child classes will run it and can override it as well if they require a specific implementation.
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("This Start method will now be called by all children.");
    }
}


public class Building : Unit
{
    
    protected override void Start()
    {
        // call the base Start method on Unit.
        base.Start();
    
        // Now add this building’s particular Start code.
        Debug.Log (“Building specific Start code!”);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this. I ended up adding both Script Components to the Building GameObject because other parts of my code did not work if I did not reference the Unit class specifically. But that's another question.

Comment: @StephGC hmmm.. I have a sneaky suspicion what issues you might be running in to. If you've checked to see if a component is specifically a `Unit`, you wouldn't get the `Building.Mover` field. You want to extend this question? Otherwise I'll keep an eye out for any further question from you.

Comment: I think it is actually linked to what @MickyD is refering to: I have a Start method that I want to modularise at the level of Unit. This is done to add any Unit to a list of all Units, upon the creation of the Unit.
But it does not get triggered for the child Building, so the Buildings are not put inside the Unit list:
`public class UnitSelections : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Unit> unitList = new List<Unit>();
    public List<Unit> unitsSelected = new List<Unit>();
...
}`

Comment: @StephGC Ahhh.. if you want to expose the base `Start()' so that Unity can see for a Building and call it, then you'd want to define the `Unit` start as either `public` or `protected`.  That way, when Unity looks at a `Building`, it WILL see the `Start()` method, and call it. Otherwise the Start method is hidden on the base Unit object, and Unity won't see it. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I have fleshed out the OP to explain the context :)

Comment: Ok this solved it. I moved the code from the Start method of `Building` to its Awake method, so that then the Start method of `Unit` does not get overridden. Unless we can define it so that the Start method of a Child implements the Start method of its parent + the Child specific implementation ?

Comment: @StephGC there sure is a way… updated the answer. 

Comment: Oh waow, this is great. Alright, I think that wraps it all up, thank you so much for your time ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As you can see the building component has all fields of unit component. So yes it inherits everything. The building  component is unit component + all inside (start, update, CreateMover). If you add building component and unit component then you have 2 unit components where one of them is extended with start, update and CreateMover.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it seems obvious with the screenshot, but some other parts of my code expected the Unit class specifically and that made me doubt adding only the Buidling Script Component. So all clear now, thanks :) !